# Disable div and span marking

Tags: html, css, mobile-website

On mobile devices when I tap on my hamburger icon there's some kind of blur on it. I don't want it to be there.

Here is screenshot of problem:

[image: CLICK]

On desktop devices everything is ok. But on mobiles or Chrome's responsive devices simulator when I press and hold for a while my hamburger there is a blur on it.

And here's my code in snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".hamburger").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("is-active");
  });
});
```

```css
.hamburger {
    margin-top: 15px;
}
.hamburger .line{
    width: 25px;
    height: 3px;
    background-color: #ecf0f1;
    display: block;
    margin: 4px auto;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.hamburger:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
}
#hamburger-9{
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
#hamburger-9.is-active{
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.noselect {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
     -khtml-user-select: none;
       -moz-user-select: none; 
        -ms-user-select: none; 
            user-select: none; 
    outline-style: none;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#hamburger-9.is-active .line{
    width: 30px;
}
#hamburger-9.is-active .line:nth-child(2){
    opacity: 0;
}
#hamburger-9.is-active .line:nth-child(1){
    -webkit-transform: translateY(6px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(6px);
    -o-transform: translateY(6px);
    transform: translateY(6px);
}
#hamburger-9.is-active .line:nth-child(3){
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-8px) rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-8px) rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform: translateY(-8px) rotate(90deg);
    transform: translateY(-8px) rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hamburger noselect" id="hamburger-9">
  <span class="line"></span>
  <span class="line"></span>
  <span class="line"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: by "blur" do you mean that blue box around your hamburger icon? if so you could try this css style: `.hamburger:focus { outline: none; }`

Comment: it is not working :(

Comment: you should also try `.hamburger .line:focus { outline: none; }`

Comment: also didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is likely webkit's tap highlight: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-tap-highlight-color

```
* {
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
```

(from your screenshot)

Are you using transforms to turn the x from a + by chance?

Comment: It's not really 'blurry' so careful with your descriptor choice. - and you're photo was all blurred out - which was kinda confusing give the use of that word. : )